# Mail icon using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to create an email icon in CSS. Is this the right way to code as UI or Front-end Developer?

[**Check out my Codepen here.**](http://codepen.io/rrbairar/pen/PpRVWe)

```css
.container {
  border-left: 10px solid #80BD9E;
  border-right: 10px solid #80BD9E;
  background: #F98886;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
  border-right: 254px solid transparent;
  border-top: 250px solid #80BD9E;
}
.arrow-down1 {
  top:22%;
  left:25.5%;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
  border-right: 254px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 250px solid #f98886;
  border-radius:6px;
}
.topLayer {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 505px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 24.5%;
  margin-top: -9.9%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="topLayer">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <div class="arrow-down1">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cool to see that you're trying to be creative with html&css. Like suggested before me it is probebly best/easiest to just use fontAwesome, Material Icons or Bootstrap Icons.

But if you do make icons yourself try to use a 'container-div' with `position: relative` and all the elements of your icon `position: absolute`. Right now the email does not render the right way:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... I was just trying out to make it using css.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I needed it to embed in an email because imaging is so restrictive:

[check it out in action (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/k65fx4yh/1/)

SCSS: size should scale and color will change with a change of the variables

```
$mail-size: 50;
$letter-color: white;
$letter-accent-color: gray;

.container{
  border: $mail-size * .06 + px solid $letter-accent-color;
  background-color: $letter-color;
  height: $mail-size * 1.4 + px;
  width: $mail-size * 2 + px;
  border-radius:6px;
}

.arrow-down {
  border-left: $mail-size + px solid transparent;
  border-right: $mail-size + px solid transparent;
  border-top: $mail-size + px solid $letter-accent-color;
}
.arrow-down1 {
  margin-top:-$mail-size * 1.008 + px;
  margin-left: -$mail-size * .92 + px;
  border-left: $mail-size * .92 + px solid transparent;
  border-right: $mail-size * .92 + px solid transparent;
  border-top: $mail-size * .92 + px solid $letter-color;
  border-radius:0px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <div class="arrow-down1">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as it turns out, this will not work in email templates either lol

Answer (score 0):

Delete the third box. After that this looks fine.

```css
.container {
  border-left: 10px solid #80BD9E;
  border-right: 10px solid #80BD9E;
  background: #F98886;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
  border-right: 254px solid transparent;
  border-top: 250px solid #80BD9E;
}
.topLayer {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 505px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 24.5%;
  margin-top: -9.9%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="topLayer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="arrow-down">


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it's easier to use Font Awesome: http://fontawesome.io/